# Where do I put Freemember Password Reset code?

Tags: freemember

This is embarrassing because I *know* I have asked this before...

What's the trick to getting the reset email link to load the template with the Freemember Password Reset code? Does the template have to be named something specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password reset link in the email should already have the code in it (it is stored in a segment variable which is passed to your password reset template).

Update: If the email sent still includes the default link to the standard EE reset password page, it is probably because you didn't specify which template your custom reset page is on with the reset parameter:

```
{exp:freemember:forgot_password return="account/forgot_sent" reset="account/reset"}
    <!-- forgot password template -->
{/exp:freemember:forgot_password}
```

Docs: https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/blob/master/docs/forgot_password_tag.md#reset

Comment: The email generates a link like this: http://mydomain.com/?ACT=18&id=rjyglbc5nhyg but even though I have a template set up with the password reset stuff (currently http://mydomain.com/account/password_reset), when I click the email's link I only ever get the wonky EE default thing.   EE 2.5.5, Freemember 2.2.1

Comment: See edit. Does that help?

Comment: Yes... It helps me feel like a total idiot! My apologies for wasting your time due to my poor documentation reading abilities! Everything works as advertised now that I've actually got the proper parameters in place. Thanks for creating Freemember; it's a perfect solution for the majority of our needs.

Comment: No worries! I'm sure this will help someone else too, you probably aren't the first person to run into this.